# TFS 2017: Kanban card default Test Plan

Tags: tfs, automated-tests

I'm asking this question on behalf of a colleague (which means I may have the terminology incorrect).

When a colleague adds a Test Case to a card, a requirement test suite is created in the wrong test plan.

We don't want a test suite to be created, we just want the test cases to be on the card itself.

How can we change this behaviour in TFS?

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any settings for the test plan creation. The test plan creation works with next steps (tested on vsts):

1. System tries to find any plan with requirement. If there is no any plan then next.
2. System tries to find any plan with the iteration path from requirement. If plan exists system will import requirement to that plan. If there is no any plan then next.
3. System creates plan with iteration path from requirement and with requirement.

So you may use a workaround:

1. Create iterations for all test plans that you plan to use.
2. Assign needed iteration for selected test plan.
3. Assign needed iteration for requirements that will be used for testing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to disable this behavior. But you can create a test plan and then configure the VSTS/TFS to place all the test case there:

1. Click the "Configure team settings" button:
   [image]
2. Navigate to "Tests" panel and then choose "Select a test plan".
   [image]